# How to convert SQL Query to CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

How to convert this query :

```
SELECT pembelian_detail_tb.kode_beli, pembelian_detail_tb.kode_produk, produk_tb.nama, pembelian_detail_tb.jumlah
FROM pembelian_detail_tb
INNER JOIN produk_tb ON pembelian_detail_tb.kode_produk = produk_tb.kode_produk;
```

I have try many code, and i still got undefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('pembelian_detail_tb.kode_beli, pembelian_detail_tb.kode_produk, produk_tb.nama, pembelian_detail_tb.jumlah')
->from('pembelian_detail_tb')
->join('produk_tb', 'pembelian_detail_tb.kode_produk = produk_tb.kode_produk', 'inner')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Query Bindings once a join is involved in a query:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html

search page for "query bindings"

this escapes values for you of course and if you need to debug dump $this->db->last_query();